How to Run Azure DevOps pipeline on Databricks using Serverless cluster instead
I am writing an Azure Devops pipeline to run Unit Tests with nutter on Databricks.
As described in the nutter documentation, this is the code to run the tests:
nutter run /Shared/ $CLUSTER --recursive --junit_report

However, I want to use the Serverless cluster from my Databricks environment, and not a specific cluster resource. So I do not have a ClusterID for the Serverless resource.
How can I use the Serverless to run this?

Hi @SergioPolimante, Have you got a chance to check the answer below? it seemed that we could not use nutter run without a cluster and it was by design of nutter CLI rather than Azure DevOps. Hope the information helps. cheers.

As far as I have tested with nutter, it is not possible to execute nutter runner without a cluster, no matter we run the cell or trigger the test by nutter CLI via Pipelines or local PowerShell prompt.

Azure pipelines simply use nutter CLI to authenticate access to DATABRICKS_HOST against DATABRICKS_TOKEN and proceed to trigger nutter tests to be executed on the target cluster; this is the same behavior as that of the execution triggered by local PowerShell.
PowerShell script
pip install nutter

$env:DATABRICKS_HOST="https://adb-xxxxxx.azuredatabricks.net/"
$env:DATABRICKS_TOKEN="xxxxxx"
$CLUSTER = "xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx"

nutter list /shared

nutter run /Shared/ $CLUSTER --recursive --junit_report


From the troubleshooting perspective of Azure DevOps, please be advised to make sure that your tool set supports your required functionality or feature before integrating in pipelines.
